# directive not accepted in testbed declarations due to "Angular Dependency Injection" error

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular9

### update

looking into this a bit longer, it turned out the initial error was for lacking BrowserDynamicTestingModule in my jest setup .. there are also ways of passing a mock ElementRef as a provider to be rid of the error. 
However, doing either of these does not result in the test actually working. I created a new project with nothing added except this directive, so it is not in jest, and still I cannot get a passing set of tests.

--

For some reason, uniquely when I add my directive to the testbed declarations, I am getting:

```
 This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection because its dependency at index 0 of the parameter list is invalid.
    This can happen if the dependency type is a primitive like a string or if an ancestor of this class is missing an Angular decorator.

    Please check that 1) the type for the parameter at index 0 is correct and 2) the correct Angular decorators are defined for this class and its ancestors
```

I would like this directive and spec to work

### directive

```js
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  HostListener
} from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  selector: '[common-click-outside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
  @Output('common-click-outside') clickOutsideEmitter: EventEmitter<
    any
  > = new EventEmitter()

  constructor (private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target']) onClick (
    targetElement: ElementRef
  ) {
    const isClickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(
      targetElement
    )

    if (!isClickedInside) this.clickOutsideEmitter.next()
  }
}
```

### spec

```js
import { ElementRef, Component, DebugElement } from '@angular/core'
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing'
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser'

import { ClickOutsideDirective } from './click-outside.directive'

@Component({
  template: `
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="inside" (common-click-outside)="directiveDidFire = true">
        <span class="inner-child"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="outside"></div>
    </div>
  `
})
class MockClickOutsideComponent {
  directiveDidFire: boolean
}

describe('ClickOutsideDirective', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MockClickOutsideComponent>
  let component: MockClickOutsideComponent
  let insideEl: DebugElement
  let innerChildEl: DebugElement
  let outsideEl: DebugElement

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MockClickOutsideComponent, ClickOutsideDirective]
    })
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MockClickOutsideComponent)
    component = fixture.componentInstance
    insideEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.inside'))
    innerChildEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.inner-child'))
    outsideEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.outside'))
  })

  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const insideEl = document.createElement('div')
    const insideElRef = new ElementRef<HTMLElement>(insideEl)

    const directive = new ClickOutsideDirective(insideElRef)

    expect(directive).toBeDefined()
  })

  it('should emit on click outside', () => {
    outsideEl.triggerEventHandler('click', null)
    fixture.detectChanges()

    expect(component.directiveDidFire).toBeTruthy()
  })

  it('should not emit on click inside', () => {
    insideEl.triggerEventHandler('click', null)
    fixture.detectChanges()

    expect(component.directiveDidFire).toBeFalsy()
  })

  it('should not emit on click of child of inside element', () => {
    innerChildEl.triggerEventHandler('click', null)
    fixture.detectChanges()

    expect(component.directiveDidFire).toBeFalsy()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had to do a couple of things.

There was some setup I needed for the testbed that is done for me in the npm library [jest-preset-angular](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular).. The instructions the provided on the github there however did not get the project working for me. Since I had manually set up earlier without this (based on docs from jest itself), I conformed my project to this [guide](https://www.amadousall.com/how-to-set-up-angular-unit-testing-with-jest/) to get working tests again. Unfortunately, this *dramatically* slows down the testing, to the point where I think karma is neck-in-neck with jest now, and faster on re-runs. But hey, it works :)

In the test, the big change is to manually dispatch the event rather than just triggering the event handler,

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing'
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { ElementRef, Component, DebugElement } from '@angular/core'

import { ClickOutsideDirective } from './click-outside.directive'

@Component({
  template: `
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="inside" (common-click-outside)="directiveDidFire = true">
        <span class="inner-child"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="outside"></div>
    </div>
  `
})
class MockClickOutsideComponent {
  directiveDidFire: boolean = false
}

describe('ClickOutsideDirective', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MockClickOutsideComponent>
  let component: MockClickOutsideComponent
  let insideEl: DebugElement
  let innerChildEl: DebugElement
  let outsideEl: DebugElement
  let syntheticEvent: MouseEvent

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MockClickOutsideComponent, ClickOutsideDirective]
    }).compileComponents()
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MockClickOutsideComponent)
    component = fixture.componentInstance

    insideEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.inside'))
    innerChildEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.inner-child'))
    outsideEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.outside'))

    syntheticEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
      view: window,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true
    })
  })

  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const insideEl = document.createElement('div')
    const insideElRef = new ElementRef<HTMLElement>(insideEl)

    const directive = new ClickOutsideDirective(insideElRef)

    expect(directive).toBeDefined()
  })

  it('should emit on click outside', () => {
    outsideEl.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(syntheticEvent)
    fixture.detectChanges()

    expect(component.directiveDidFire).toBeTruthy()
  })

  it('should not emit on click inside', () => {
    insideEl.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(syntheticEvent)
    fixture.detectChanges()

    expect(component.directiveDidFire).toBeFalsy()
  })

  it('should not emit on click of child of inside element', () => {
    innerChildEl.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(syntheticEvent)
    fixture.detectChanges()

    expect(component.directiveDidFire).toBeFalsy()
  })
})
```